# How is it possible to fetch only the first item of the same element type inside an array php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with different data in it for example like this

```php
array( 4 => 'pc', 7 => 'mouse', 13 => 'keyboard', 14 => 'laptop', 15 => 'laptop' );
```

how do I go about to only fetch the first "Laptop", I was able to fetch them but they come both at the same time I used the $key as $value inside a foreach but it still returns both if I give it a condition to only show laptops and the data changes so it's not hardcoded to be the same

Comment: Can you add the code you have and explain what output you want to have? What do you mean exactly by `fetch the first "Laptop"`?

Comment: I mean just to display the first one inside that array even if there are 2 of the same data

Comment: Have you tried the function `array_search()`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem:

```
$arr = array( 4 => 'pc', 7 => 'mouse', 13 => 'keyboard', 14 => 'laptop', 15 => 'laptop' );

// User array_search to find first occurance/key of "laptop"
$key      = array_search("laptop", $arr); // $key = 14
$value    = $arr[$key];                   // $value = "laptop"
$arr_part = [$key => $value]              // $arr_part = [14 => "laptop"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to use `array_unique($your_array);` for this.
This will remove duplicate values from your array.
Then you will only fetch one and no duplicates.

Also refer to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php